# Need to count the number of operations within a rolling 30-day period between dates in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table **Mytable**, where id - id of member and dp_id - id of departament:

```
    date                     id      dp_id
  2020-11-14 01:22:10.260  300000  002    
  2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575  001
  2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575  001
  2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575  001
  2020-11-14 00:00:00.260  300000  002
  2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575  001
  2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575  001
  2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575  002
```

If the number of operations in next 30 days from the first transaction for pair `id` - `dp_id` (`352575` - `001`) is more than 5, it should be marked as `over_lim`.

For example, if the first operation for `id`-`dp_id` was at `01: 41: 13.260`, therefore, over the next 30 days, i need to count how many operations were there and mark each transaction if there were more than 5.

i.e. `2020-11-15 01: 00: 43.600 352575 001` operation will be the 5th operation from the the first entry by `id`-`dp_id` pair, therefore we mark it as `over_lim`. And so on for each period - we need to take the first transaction of the period and see how much it was in the next 30 days.

Expected output, where `tr_count` - count of each transaction per pair `id`-`dp_id`, `over_lim`- our mark, that it's a overlimit transaction(>=5):

```
  date                     id      dp_id tr_count over_lim
2020-11-14 01:22:10.260  300000  002   1        False
2020-11-14 01:41:13.260  352575  001   1        False
2020-11-14 16:39:31.910  352575  001   2        False
2020-11-14 23:39:52.510  352575  001   3        False
2020-11-14 00:00:00.260  300000  002   2        False
2020-11-15 00:01:20.710  352575  001   4        False
2020-11-15 01:00:43.600  352575  001   5        True
2020-11-15 13:41:19.410  352575  002   1        False
```

Comment: Why isn't the last row marked as well?  It is the 6th which is bigger than 5.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because it's a new id-dp_id pair 352575 - 002, so it first entry for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar approach gives me the result you want ( *I change field `date` by `date_oper`* )

```
SQL> with t as
  2   (
  3     select to_date('2020-11-14 01:22:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 300000 id, '002' dp_id from dual union all
  4     select to_date('2020-11-14 01:41:13','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 352575 id, '001' dp_id from dual union all
  5     select to_date('2020-11-14 16:39:31','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 352575 id, '001' dp_id from dual union all
  6     select to_date('2020-11-14 23:39:52','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 352575 id, '001' dp_id from dual union all
  7     select to_date('2020-11-14 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 300000 id, '002' dp_id from dual union all
  8     select to_date('2020-11-15 00:01:20','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 352575 id, '001' dp_id from dual union all
  9     select to_date('2020-11-15 01:00:43','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 352575 id, '001' dp_id from dual union all
 10     select to_date('2020-11-15 13:41:19','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') date_oper, 352575 id, '002' dp_id from dual
 11   )
 12   select t.*,
 13   count(*) over (partition by id, dp_id order by date_oper range between interval '30' day preceding and current row) as tr_count,
 14   (case when count(*) over (partition by id, dp_id order by date_oper range between interval '30' day preceding and current row) >= 5
 15    then 'true' else 'false'
 16    end) as over_lim
 17*  from t order by date_oper
SQL> /

DATE_OPER                   ID DP_   TR_COUNT OVER_
------------------- ---------- --- ---------- -----
2020-11-14 00:00:00     300000 002          1 false
2020-11-14 01:22:10     300000 002          2 false
2020-11-14 01:41:13     352575 001          1 false
2020-11-14 16:39:31     352575 001          2 false
2020-11-14 23:39:52     352575 001          3 false
2020-11-15 00:01:20     352575 001          4 false
2020-11-15 01:00:43     352575 001          5 true
2020-11-15 13:41:19     352575 002          1 false

8 rows selected.
```

You can check here

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6110fbc1208b3cbfab7a26515276e623)

Comment: looks like it works better with row_number(), but when i applied it instead of count(*) at tr_count, i get that  missing right parenthesis error. also in your virtual db example you've got correct answer, but at my masssive tables its just sums total count of each pair id - dp_id in tr_count for ex 6, instead of 1,2,3 etc

Comment: @Kurasao, `row_number()` does not admit range, so it can't work. Regarding the result, perhaps you should have explained a bit better the desired output, as far as I can see my query gets the output you put as expected. Can you edit the question and add more rows to understand better the logic you expect ?

Comment: just fixed my problem, should use timestamp date column 11/11/2020 6:13:45,000000 , not date 11/11/2020, it cause in total sum of count. thanx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count(*)` with `range`:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by id
                      order by date
                      range between interval '30' day preceding and interval '0' day preceding
                     ) as tr_count,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by id
                                 order by date
                                 range between interval '30' day preceding and interval '0' day preceding
                           ) >= 5
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as over_lim
from t;
```

If you want only the fifth one to be `'true'`, then change the `>= 5` to `= 5`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed404a813b83be41a799439d6d38f1b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think it will be better to use range between interval '-30' day preceding and CURRENT ROW

Comment: @GordonLinoff i dont get a correct cumulative total for each entry in tr_count column, how can i change this skript to achieve result like in Expected output above

Comment: @Kurasao . . . I fixed the typos.  I think it will work now.  I'm not sure if you want `>= 5` or `= 5`, though.

Comment: @GordonLinoff looks like it works better with row_number(), but when i applied it instead of count(*) at tr_count, i get that  missing right parenthesis error. also in your virtual db example you've got correct answer, but at my masssive tables its just sums total count of each pair id - dp_id in tr_count for ex 6, instead of 1,2,3 etc